# no value return for php xml simpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

So  far i have not been able to return any value for id. here is my code.

```
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Benchmark id="IE8"></Benchmark>

XML;

$sxml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

var_dump($sxml);

$name = (string) $sxml->Benchmark['id'];

echo $name;
```

this is my var dump

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[1]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string 'IE8' (length=3)
```

I basically just want to return the id value: IE8 in Benchmark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new `SimpleXMLElement`, the returned object represents the *root* element of your XML file.

`$sxml` is your `<Benchmark>` element, `$sxml->Benchmark` doesn't exist.

```
$name = (string) $sxml['id'];
```